# An approximation about the prime-counting function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

$\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function (i.e the number of primes less than or equal to an integer $x$), $li(x)$ is the logarithmic integral and $mod$ is the modulo (i.e the remainder of the division of $li(x)$ by $\pi(x)$).

I am interested in studying the prime-counting function and I have an approximation but I don't know if this result is interesting or already exists. In particular, I have seen a limit in the literature about $li(x)$ and $\pi(x)$:
$$\lim_{x -> +\infty}\frac{\pi(x)}{li(x)}=1$$
But nothing about the modulo.
We have:
$$(\pi(x)+0.5+\ln(\ln(x))+\sum_{k=1}^x {\frac{\ln^k(x)}{kk!}})-(li(x) mod \pi(x)) \approx 2\pi(x)$$
For example: $x=10$ we have:
$$(\pi(10)+0.5+\ln(\ln(10))+\sum_{k=1}^{10} {\frac{\ln^k(10)}{kk!}})-(li(10) mod \pi(10))$$
$$=4+0.5+\ln(\ln(10))+4.75432-(2.1655)$$
$$\approx 7.92$$
$$\approx 2\pi(10)$$

I would be curious to know if this approximation is correct and if this is the case, how to prove it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please use \ln in math mode to get $\ln$ rather than $ln$ (or just \log really).

Comment: Finally the formula is already known and uses the Euler-Mascheroni constant instead of $0.5$ and uses an infinite summand.